# Error: 26 / Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Имею win 10  и SQL Server 2017. В визуал студии запускаю проект, который работе на других машинах. Но на мое, выходит ошибка.
При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Ошибка при обнаружении указанного сервера или экземпляра)

Понимаю что что то с портами, но не могу правильно настроить, сам сервер работает, база в нем тоже. Брандмауэр отключил.

Comment: Из вопроса неясно, убедились ли Вы, *что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения.*

Comment: @Yaant вроде убедился, порт разрешил, далее делал так --Сеть SQL Server   Конфигурация -> Протоколы для SQLEXPRESS.     
Открыв его, вы должны перейти на вкладку IP-адреса, и для меня,   изменение IPAll на TCP-порт 1433 и удаление динамических портов.

Comment: инстанс тако указываю в конфиге Source=DESKTOP-34RBM61\SQLEXPRESS;